# preg_split vs mb_split

Tags: php, regex, split, pcre

According to the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), the `u` modifier of PCRE regular expressions enables UTF-8 support for both the pattern and the subject string.

Considering this, is there any difference between using PCRE expressions with the `u` modifier and the corresponding `mb_*` multibyte string functions? (Assuming that all strings are UTF-8 encoded.)

---

As an example, consider `preg_split` vs `mb_split`: Both

```
preg_split('/' . $pattern . '/u', $string);
```

and

```
mb_split($pattern, $string);
```

seem to return identical results. So, which one should be preferred? Does it even matter?

Comment: I would say this is pretty much the same as comparing `preg_match` and `strpos` for a static string search.

Comment: Why? `strpos` doesn't support regular expressions, or am I wrong about that?

Comment: "**for a static string search**" - when the string is constant, not a regex...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol preg_split / mb_split are both for regex, so I don't understand the analogy preg_match / strpos

Comment: .. Oh. Oops. Ignore me then.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The main difference is that `preg_` functions use the [pcre library](http://pcre.org/original/pcre.txt), when the `mb_ereg_` functions (including `mb_split`) use the [oniguruma library](https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma) (used in ruby before the version 2.0).

The main reason is that oniguruma can deal with multiple encodings *(ASCII, UTF-8, UTF-16BE, UTF-16LE, UTF-32BE, UTF-32LE, EUC-JP, EUC-TW, EUC-KR, EUC-CN, Shift_JIS, Big5, GB18030, KOI8-R, CP1251, ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-2, ISO-8859-3, ISO-8859-4, ISO-8859-5, ISO-8859-6, ISO-8859-7, ISO-8859-8, ISO-8859-9, ISO-8859-10, ISO-8859-11, ISO-8859-13, ISO-8859-14, ISO-8859-15, ISO-8859-16)* when pcre can't.

Note that a lot of encodings available for `mb_` functions like `mb_detect_encoding` are not in this list (UTF-7, ArmSCII-8, CP866 for example) limiting the relevance of `mb_ereg_` functions. *(Since you need to convert the string to a supported encoding before working on it, and to convert it back after.)*

The two regex engines share more or less the same features, nevertheless you can find some differences (not exhaustive, as it comes):

Oniguruma doesn't support:

- one letter unicode shorthand character classes to be written without curly brackets.
  Example: `\pN` is seen as `pN`, you need to write:`\p{N}`
- the unicode character classes: Xan, Xps, Xsp, Xwd
- non-escaped square brackets in a character class: Oniguruma see `[][]` as two empty character classes, when pcre see a character class that contains `]` and `[`
- the `\K` feature
- the `\R` alias for newline sequences
- named groups that use the Python syntax `(?P<name>...)`. Only `(?<name>...)` or `(?'name'...)` are allowed.
- group references with something else than the Oniguruma syntax: `\g<name>` (Perl syntax `(?&name)` and `(?1)` or `(?R)` are not allowed).
- backtracking control verbs

PCRE doesn't support:

- duplicated named groups (by default). You need to use the `(?J)` modifier to switch on this feature.
- numbered back-references with `\k<...>` syntax. You can write `\k<name>` but not `\k<1>` or `\k<-1>`.
- back-references to a specific nest level. Oniguruma is able to do that using `\k<name+n>` where `n` is the nest level.

To match newlines with the dot, Oniguruma uses the `m` modifier, when PCRE uses the `s` modifier.
In `mb_ereg_` functions, the dot matches newlines by default. (So the `m` modifier is on by default).

PCRE uses the `s` modifier to match newline with the dot. The `m` modifier behaves differently in PCRE, it changes the meaning of `^` and `$` anchors from "start" and "end" of the string to "start" and "end" of the line.

With Oniguruma, the meaning of these anchors doesn't change, they match always the start and end of the line. To match the limit of the string, it uses `\A` and `\z` also available with PCRE.

Note that Oniguruma has been forked to give Onigmo (used in current Ruby versions) that implements more Perl features and syntactic elements, and that is more similar to PCRE.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you're working strictly with `UTF-8` you will be fine with either. If you were using another `charset` then it would be recommended to use `mb_split()` since the `u` modifier with PCRE does not allow you to specify the `charset`, instead treating the strings as `UTF-8`.

In regards to scaling and long-term viability I would recommend using `mb_split()` from the start so that you are covered in case something other than `UTF-8` is used or needed down the road.

Comment: You mean `mb_split` instead of `preg_split`, don't you? You can set the encoding with `mb_regex_encoding` then for the `mb_*` functions.